# Powershell and calling function scope

Tags: powershell

It's possible to force *Exit* of a function *Parent* that call a Function *Child*, from function *Child*?
Example code:

```
function Parent
{
   Write-Host "I'm Calling Parent Function"
   Child
   Write-Host "Code...Code..."
}

function Child
{
   Write-Host "I'm Calling Child Function"
   # END function:Parent
   Write-Host "Parent Ended!"
}

PS> Parent
PS> I'm Calling Parent Function
I'm Calling Child Function
Parent Ended!
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Not without either returning a value which the parent then checks to see whether it should continue execution or not, or by throwing an terminating exception from the `Child` method. Of course, both of these approaches would also ensure `Child` is also ended. `Child` will always end before `Parent` will end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ( using `break` I think is the dos command or an internal powershell command because `get-command break` returns error)

```
function Child
{
   Write-Host "I'm Calling Child Function"
   break
   Write-Host "Parent Ended!"
}
```

Comment: Maybe that's the command from `help about_break`, but they don't mention this behavior (or I missed it). Glad you found it.